# Richfaces: a4j support (action, actionListener) for an inputText inside a dataTable

Tags: datatable, richfaces, action, actionlistener, ajax4jsf

I have a JSP page in which the user must be allowed to edit data from a column and, when the form is submitted, update the respective table in database. Number of rows from this table is variable.

For the editable info field I have the following code snippet (let's name it **Block A**) in a JSP page:

```
  <h:inputText value="#{myBackingBean.theFieldValue}" >
    <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBackingBean.theActionListener}" action="#{myBackingBean.theAction}"/>
  </h:inputText>
```

The following code snippet (let's name it **Block B**) is from the backing bean:

```
public String theAction() {
    String outcome = null;
    System.out.println("the action method was invoked");
    return outcome;
}

public void theActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("the action listener method was invoked");
}
```

As you can see, whenever these methods are invoked that is printed to console output.

My problem is:
When I put **Block A** inside the following block (a **single** inputText component in the form):

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  (...)
    here I put Block A
  (...)
</h:form>
```

The **Block B** is invoked without problem. But, if instead I put the **Block A** inside a rich:dataTable component as I need it (**multiple** inputText components in the form) in order to store each row's inputText value to database (here is where I need to invoke action and/or actionListener methods):

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <rich:dataTable id="myDataTable" value="#{myBackingBean.myObjectList}" var="item" binding="#{myBackingBean.myObjectHtmlDataTable}" rendered="#{!empty myBackingBean.myObjectList}" rows="20">
    (...)
      <rich:column>
          here I put Block A
      </rich:column>
    (...)
  </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

in this case, the **Block B** is never reached.

I'm working with **JSF 1.2**, and **RichFaces 3.3.3**, all needed beans and navigation rules are correctly configured. All needed getters and setters are in their respective classes.

Please could you give me some advice to make my code to work properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it works very fine. Both the action methods can  run.

It may due to other components  in your form have errors when processed on the server such that the  bean 's methods cannot run .

You can try to limit the server only processes the changed `<h:inputText>` using [`<a4j:region>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_region.html) .If the action methods can then be called , it could be confirmed that it is due to other components in your form.

```
<rich:column>
  <a4j:region>
        <h:inputText value="#{myBackingBean.theFieldValue}" >
                <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBackingBean.theActionListener}"   action="#{myBackingBean.theAction}"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </a4j:region>
</rich:column>
```

If your `<h:form>` has the `onsubmit()` event handler , please also make sure it returns true in order to submit the form.